# I have a pyspark DataFrame and I want to cast the type of it's columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
df = spark.read.csv("Sales_December.csv", header=True)

df.printSchema()
```

returns string for Order Id

I want to change the schema so it returns int for order id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

df = df.withColumn('order id', func.col('order id').cast(IntegerType()))
```

Comment: But i want it to be the same column

Answer (score 0):

you can use withColumn.

WithColumn syntax -->withColumn(colName : String, col : Column) : DataFrame

For example:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("Order Id",col("Order Id").cast(IntegerType())) 
df2.printSchema()
```